# Buck loop transfer function

Tags: buck, transfer-function, control-loop

I saw two types of buck loop transfer function from two sheets, and the difference is the second type didn't consider H(s) from compensation network.

Here is the first type, error-amp with compensation,and the H(s) is R1/(R1+R2)
[image]

[image]

Here is the second type.  It seems not to consider the gain(R1/(R1+R2)).

Since when doning ac analysis, resistor(R2) doesn't make any changes to transfer function of compensator.

[image]

[image]

I think T1(s)*H(s) of first equal to Compenstor of second, but there's a difference of constant gain.
Does anything I think wrong?

Comment: What are the values of components ( Rx and Cx)?

Comment: I'm also curious how, in the first diagram above, the open loop gain includes the negative feedback, H(s). This may be a novel idea to which I've so far not yet been exposed. Or is that *before* connecting it up to the sum, so that you capture everything just prior to the summation?